# InnoDB: does `redo log` contain initial value and final value? or just final value?

Tags: mysql, innodb, transaction-log, transaction

```
start transaction;
update users set age = 34 where user_id = 3 // update age from 30 to 34 years old.
....
....
```

when I am updating the age of this user, InnDB will write redo log.

- What's the structure of redo log?
- Does it contain `initial value 30 and final value 34`? or just contains new value 34?

Comment: [This tool](https://github.com/jeremycole/innodb_ruby/blob/a9ad06c8aea200ff0a22c28ad6e251232ab10315/bin/innodb_log) might give a few clues.

Comment: OK, it is helpful, but did it give you the answer?  If so, what is the answer?  (Don't leave other readers hanging!)

Comment: I just tried this tool, it doesn't work for me. An error is raised.  `innodb_log  -f /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_logfile0 -f /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_logfile1 log-follow-tail-summary`